# Is the colon-based template syntax for $resource's url parameter following a standard, or is it AngularJS-specific?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rfc, hateoas, uritemplate

A REST service I'm working on is sending HATEOAS links back to its AngularJS client. For a few of them, we can't provide the full URL (for lack of information), just a URI Template. We want to follow RFC 6570 ([section 3.2.7, "Path-Style Parameter Expansion"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.7)) to do that. The syntax is `{;varName,foo}` which the client is supposed to expand to `;varName=bar;foo=baz`

A colleague made me aware of [AngularJS's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for `$resource`, where a syntax with colons is used: `:varName`
I suppose the equivalent for that would be section 3.2.2 in that RFC (simple string expansion): `{varName}`, e.g. `example.com/order/{orderId}/` would be `example.com/order/:orderId/` in that syntax, and expand to `.../order/123/`

So, first of all, could the colon syntax be used for matrix parameter templates?

Secondly, is that colon syntax defined in a standard/rfc, or is it AngularJS-specific?
(The service is supposed to be client-agnostic.)

Last but not least, does AngularJS support RFC6570 out of the box?

P.S.: This is a [cross-post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/_7cLQi1q0uI/1YuBYDL5AgAJ) from the Angualr-JS mailing list...

Answer (score 2):

you're asking a lot of questions.

No, that angular format is NOT RFC 6570 compliant.

I believe the : prefixed variable syntax for URLs start with Ruby on Rails.  I do not know of a spec for that.

googling `RFC6570 javascript` and `RFC6570 angular` led to numerous results. i might suggest traverson which has angular extensions, but no it's not supported out of the box.